# Call from Kotlin a Java generic method defined with multiple bounds, one bound is itself a generic type

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, kubernetes

I am building a Kubernetes operator in Kotlin, and I try to call a generic method that is defined with multiple bounds. The method signature is the following:

```java
<C extends Namespaceable<C> & KubernetesClient> LeaderElectorBuilder<C> leaderElector();
```

You can find the source code here: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/1150135f9febfd000396c031532efe5856037043/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/KubernetesClient.java#L427-L433

The multiple bounds syntax in Java allows to define multiple constraints on a type used in a generic class or method definition. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_generics/java_generics_multiple_bounds.htm

I try to call that method in Kotlin, but it fails to infer the type, and none of my definitions are accepted by the compiler.

If I do:

```kotlin
client.leaderElector()
```

Kotlin will complain that there is "**Not enough information to infer type variable C**".

Any explicit type is refused, typically:

```kotlin
client.leaderElector<KubernetesClient>()
```

Kotlin will complain that "**Type argument is not within its bounds. Expected: Namespaceable<KubernetesClient!>! Found: KubernetesClient!**"

And the opposite ("**Expected: KubernetesClient! Found: Namespaceable<KubernetesClient>!**") if I use `Namespaceable<KubernetesClient>` for the explicit type.

How to invoke this method correctly in Kotlin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ... I mean, neither of those types *do* satisfy the bounds. Pick a type (or create a class) that actually satisfies them and it'll probably work? From what I can see of the code, a `Namespaceable<KubernetesClient>` is not necessarily a `KubernetesClient` and a `KubernetesClient` is not necessarily a `Namespaceable<KubernetesClient>`.

Comment: Maybe you need a type that unions `KubernetesClient` and `Namespaceable<T>` for instance `class MyClass : KubernetesClient,  Namespaceable<MyClass>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help.

Indeed a custom class unioning the two possible types to match the generic definition was the solution.

Below is an example of a class that is using this approach and makes Kotlin compiler happy:

```kotlin
package org.mypackage

import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.Namespaceable

abstract class MyClass : KubernetesClient, Namespaceable<MyClass>

class Test(kubernetesClient: KubernetesClient) {

    val kubernetesClient: KubernetesClient = DefaultKubernetesClient()

    fun test() {
        kubernetesClient.leaderElector<MyClass>()
    }
}
```